# Fancybox 2 global event error when launching without an element

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, jquery-1.9

I'm launching fancybox dynamically. I have been using this method with jquery less than 1.9.0 for a while with no problems.

However, now in JQuery 1.9.0 global events are not supported. It seems like fancybox tries to broadcast a global event when launched dynamically (not attached to a dom element like a button).

This fiddle will show you the jquery migrate error in your console. 
http://jsfiddle.net/gMeFT/2/

```
$.fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    autoScale: true,
    href: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
    type: 'ajax'
});
```

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: Almost impossible to debug with a minified file. Or, I rather would say too troublesome. Can you use a relevant non-minified fancybox version? Also, can you explain what's the problem. Warnings are warnings, I can't see an error popping up. What's your question? :)

Comment: I guess you are right. Jquery 1.9 will automatically redirect that event to 'document', and if it doesnt get detected there than it is just a problem with the plugin. I initially thought it was blocking some other script but your answer caused me to look at it differently and find the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I think I've found the solution, but unfortunately you need to hack one line in the source code.

Line 764 contains something like:

```
$.event.trigger(event + '.fb');
```

Changing it to following should do the job:

```
D.trigger(event + '.fb');
```